K3S on Ubuntu 20.04 node running frigate NVR: cannot access Coral Mini PCIe Accelerator from container even though device is there
I run a K3S cluster with several containers. One of them is my Frigate NVR. Frigate can use a coral accelerator to do object detection. Before I moved to containers I used Home Assistant OS with Frigate as a add-on and things worked beautifully. I have set up passthrough for my Frigate container and can confirm the device is actually present within the container. I've also made it privileged and have been playing with several securityContext settings:
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: frigate
  name: frigate
  namespace: frigate
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frigate
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frigate
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: frigate
        image: ghcr.io/blakeblackshear/frigate:stable
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8445
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8555
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 8555
          protocol: UDP
        envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: frigate-cm
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /dev/shm
            name: dshm
          - mountPath: /config
            name: data
          - mountPath: /media
            name: media
          - mountPath: /config/config.yaml
            subPath: config.yaml
            name: frigate-config
          - name: apex0
            mountPath: /dev/apex_0
          - name: frigate-udev
            mountPath: /run/udev
          - name: frigate-dev
            mountPath: /dev
          - name: renderer
            mountPath: /dev/dri/renderD128
      nodeSelector:
        hasZwave: 'yes'
      securityContext:
        privileged: true
        # runAsUser: 0
        # runAsGroup: 1001
        # fsGroup: 1001
        capabilities:
          add: ["SYS_ADMIN"]
        seLinuxOptions:
          level: "s0:c123,c456"
        appArmorProfile: "unconfined"
      volumes:
        - name: dshm
          emptyDir:
            medium: Memory
        - name: frigate-config
          configMap:
            name: frigate-config
        - name: data
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: frigate-pvc
        - name: media
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: frigate-media
        - name: apex0
          hostPath:
            path: /dev/apex_0
            type: CharDevice
        - name: frigate-udev
          hostPath:
            path: /run/udev
        - name: frigate-dev
          hostPath:
            path: /dev
        - name: renderer
          hostPath:
            path: /dev/dri/renderD128

/home/ansible # kubectl exec -n frigate --tty --stdin frigate-596f7fd789-zjnqm -- /bin/bash
root@frigate-596f7fd789-zjnqm:/opt/frigate# ls -al /dev/apex*
crw-rw-rw- 1 root dialout 120, 0 Jun  5 06:51 /dev/apex_0
root@frigate-596f7fd789-zjnqm:/opt/frigate#

However the device itself cannot be used from within the container because it throws a permission denied error upon opening it:
cd ~ \
 && apt-get -y update \
 && apt-get -y install curl vim \
 && mkdir test_data \
 && cd test_data \
 && curl -LO https://coral.ai/static/docs/images/parrot.jpg \
 && curl -LO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google-coral/test_data/master/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_bird_quant_edgetpu.tflite \
 && curl -LO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google-coral/test_data/master/inat_bird_labels.txt \
 && cd .. \
 && curl -LO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google-coral/pycoral/master/examples/classify_image.py\
 && python3 classify_image.py \
  --model test_data/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_bird_quant_edgetpu.tflite  \
  --labels test_data/inat_bird_labels.txt \
  --input test_data/parrot.jpg

results in (I did enable verbosity before actually running the python command):
root@frigate-596f7fd789-zjnqm:~# python3 classify_image.py \
  --model test_data/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_bird_quant_edgetpu.tflite  \
  --labels test_data/inat_bird_labels.txt \
  --input test_data/parrot.jpg
I tflite/edgetpu_manager_direct.cc:453] No matching device is already opened for shared ownership.
I driver/usb/local_usb_device.cc:944] EnumerateDevices: vendor:0x1a6e, product:0x89a
I driver/usb/local_usb_device.cc:979] EnumerateDevices: checking bus[1] port[2]
I driver/usb/local_usb_device.cc:979] EnumerateDevices: checking bus[2] port[0]
I driver/usb/local_usb_device.cc:979] EnumerateDevices: checking bus[1] port[1]
I driver/usb/local_usb_device.cc:979] EnumerateDevices: checking bus[1] port[3]
I driver/usb/local_usb_device.cc:979] EnumerateDevices: checking bus[1] port[0]
I driver/usb/local_usb_device.cc:944] EnumerateDevices: vendor:0x18d1, product:0x9302
I driver/usb/local_usb_device.cc:979] EnumerateDevices: checking bus[1] port[2]
I driver/usb/local_usb_device.cc:979] EnumerateDevices: checking bus[2] port[0]
I driver/usb/local_usb_device.cc:979] EnumerateDevices: checking bus[1] port[1]
I driver/usb/local_usb_device.cc:979] EnumerateDevices: checking bus[1] port[3]
I driver/usb/local_usb_device.cc:979] EnumerateDevices: checking bus[1] port[0]
I tflite/edgetpu_context_direct.cc:106] USB always DFU: False (default)
I tflite/edgetpu_context_direct.cc:128] USB bulk-in queue capacity: default
I tflite/edgetpu_context_direct.cc:67] Performance expectation: Max (default)
I ./driver/mmio/host_queue.h:266] Starting in normal mode
I driver/kernel/kernel_registers.cc:83] Opening /dev/apex_0. read_only=0
I tflite/edgetpu_context_direct.cc:401] Failed to open device [Apex (PCIe)] at [/dev/apex_0]: Failed precondition: Device open failed : -1 (Operation not permitted)

On the node directly, the same command results in the expected output (I had to mess about with python a bit to get all the proper wheels installed):
(myenv) maarten@k3s-node-d:~$ python3 classify_image.py \
  --model test_data/mobilenet_v2_1.0_224_inat_bird_quant_edgetpu.tflite  \
  --labels test_data/inat_bird_labels.txt \
  --input test_data/parrot.jpg
----INFERENCE TIME----
Note: The first inference on Edge TPU is slow because it includes loading the model into Edge TPU memory.
14.2ms
3.1ms
3.1ms
3.1ms
3.0ms
-------RESULTS--------
Ara macao (Scarlet Macaw): 0.76953
(myenv) maarten@k3s-node-d:~$

I have followed the instructions on https://coral.ai/docs/m2/get-started/#2a-on-linux to get the driver installed including the udev rules. In the end I did disable AppArmor completely to rule out that too, but so far had no luck being able to actually access the device from within a (debian) container. Any pointers at this point would be greatly appreciated.

Maybe there's something similar to DevicePolicy= / DeviceAllow= in systemd units (e.g. nspawn container)? https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/latest/systemd.resource-control.html
